# HQL Query fails in Hibernate MySQL

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I want to recuperate all rows from `user` table.

```
String queryS = "select u from user u";
        System.out.println("entityManager: "+(entityManager == null));
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryS);
//staff
```

The line that throws the exception is `Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryS);`

I don't know why even persistance file is ok and the table exists

The stack is:

```
10:36:06.693 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter - throwQueryException() : no errors
10:36:06.693 [AWT-EventQueue-0] DEBUG o.h.hql.antlr.HqlSqlBaseWalker - select << begin [level=1, statement=select]
```

Comment: Try "select u from User u" or the shortened query "from User"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put the name of the table in the `query` as in the `persistence` file not in database.

Answer (score 0):

If this:

```
String queryS = "select u from user u"
```

Is referred on table name you can't use createQuery method but createNativeQuery

If you want to use createQuery you must use in your query the entity/class mapped youe user table

Summarizing:

Case 1 (use createNativeQuery)

```
String queryS = "select u from user u";
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryS);
```

Case 2 (use createQuery)

```
String queryS = "select u from " + User.class.getName() + " u";
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery(queryS);
```